# INSERT INTO using format

Tags: postgresql

I want to INSERT to my database and use as shown below. I get error in `EXECUTE` line

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "validation"
```

Is it something specific i need to change here? Keep in mind that's not all columns in that table because rest will be fulfilled automaticly by db.

```
sql := format('INSERT INTO %s.%s (col1, col2,col3,col4) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)',              
    vSchemaName, vTableName, pcol1, pcol2, pcol3,pcol);         
EXECUTE sql ;
```

Comment: what is validation?

Comment: I think more info is required in order to get an answer on this question.  The error says there is a `syntax error near "validation"` but the code under it doesn't mention `validation` at all -- what is `validation`?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with the formatting of different data types, I would use placeholders:

```
sql := format('INSERT INTO %I.%I (col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4)', vSchemaName, vTableName);         
EXECUTE sql 
   using pcol1, pcol2, pcol3, pcol;
```

This assumes that your variables (`pcol1`, ...) are declared with the correct data type.